# Parse.com cloud code downloading binary

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm using Parse.com and cloud code for some server side javascript functions on my website. I usually deploy updates to cloud code through `parse deploy` in the mac terminal.

Today when I have tried to do this it has come up with:

> Downloading binary from https://parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/cli/parse-osx/latest.

I initially left this for about an hour and then cancelled it as it didn't seem to be going anywhere. I've then tried running `parse deploy` twice more but it is again just sitting there and seemingly not doing anything.

This has been working fine for the past 3 months.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

Navigating to the posted link has let me download the file (it's 6.8MB), so I possibly just need to know how to install that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Older command line tools may not be able to update themselves to v2. You will need to reinstall them (on OS X or Linux):

> curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash

You can download the latest version for your platform from https://parse.com/docs/downloads

We posted about this a couple of weeks ago in the Parse Developer forums:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/WoRnDft4qmE

Comment: Thanks Hector - accepted. Just a thought, would this not be better as a bug so that people can find it easier? I tend to navigate towards the help docs, then the bug reports if something isn't working as expected. Going through the Parse bug report didn't show anything - maybe it should?

Comment: Here's a bug that someone submitted earlier: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/469535449870644/

Comment: The Parse CLI continues to hang when downloading the latest version.  Quite inconvenient!

Answer (score 10):

Reinstalling the command line tool seems to have fixed this issue.

> curl -s https://www.parse.com/downloads/cloud_code/installer.sh | sudo /bin/bash